# xampp QStandardPaths: runtime directory '/run/user/1000' is not owned by UID 0

Tags: xampp, manjaro, kde-plasma-5, thunar

I have a problem when executing xampp and opening the application folder, since I get the following error:

```
QStandardPaths: runtime directory '/run/user/1000' is not owned by UID 0, but a directory permissions 0700 owned by UID 1000 GID 1000
QStandardPaths: runtime directory '/run/user/1000' is not owned by UID 0, but a directory permissions 0700 owned by UID 1000 GID 1000
QStandardPaths: runtime directory '/run/user/1000' is not owned by UID 0, but a directory permissions 0700 owned by UID 1000 GID 1000
QStandardPaths: runtime directory '/run/user/1000' is not owned by UID 0, but a directory permissions 0700 owned by UID 1000 GID 1000
"Session bus not found\nTo circumvent this problem try the following command (with Linux and bash)\nexport $(dbus-launch)"
```

I have dolphin installed on the system but to thunar as the default file manager.

However, xampp also takes dolphin as the main file manager

```
# sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run
Executing Dolphin with sudo is not possible due to unfixable security vulnerabilities.
```

[image]